# AssertionError: build-tools-23.0.0 doesn't match build-tools-23.0.0-preview

Tags: android, android-studio

I was having trouble with my Android Studio install, it was crashing every time I added a widget to a layout in design view.  So I downloaded the latest version which happened to be a preview build.  This fixed the crashing.  It wasn't an installer though, it was just all of the files zipped.  So I deleted my old Android Studio version and replaced it with this preview version.

Now I'm getting this error every time I open AS:
`AssertionError: build-tools-23.0.0 doesn't match build-tools-23.0.0-preview`
Also, AS no longer recognizes my phone when I try to build my app so I can't test it.  I'm not sure if these two problems are related.

Comment: you no longer need to use the preview build tools. Just use `buildToolsVersion "23" in your build.gradle file`

Comment: I just tried changing `buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc2"` to `buildToolsVersion "23"` and the `AssertionError` remains and it creates a new gradle error that it `failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.0`

Comment: google released v23 a few hrs ago. Have you updated it ?

Comment: I guess I'm using version `23.0.0 rc2` which came with the preview build.  Where can I download the latest release?  I can only find release notes for the different versions.

Comment: download them from the sdk manager

Comment: I changed the auto-updater to the canary and preview channels to fix the errors.  Thanks!

Comment: Why is the canary channel needed? Why cant the Android studio fetch it from default channel?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the exzact same issue and solved it the following way:

Go to File > Project Structure > Select Module > BuildToolsVersion

Select Build version 23.0.1 (or what ever version is the latest at the time you are reading). Then ensure that your Build Tools Version is the same as your Compiled Sdk Version.