# Android Build Tools version error libGDX project

Tags: android, sdk, build-tools

I have got following error message:

```
AssertionError: build-tools-23.0.0 doesn't match build-tools-23.0.0-preview
```

Already tried to install it, but I see this message in `Android Studio`:

[image]

Where should I update version number to latest in libGDX project?

Answer (score 1):

At first please post your `build.gradle` .

> build-tools-23.0.0 doesn't match build-tools-23.0.0-preview

I assume problem is your `buildToolsVersion`

You can use this

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
```

Comment: It is exactly the same:
`android {
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    compileSdkVersion 23`

Comment: @mum007 check comments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056781/assertionerror-build-tools-23-0-0-doesnt-match-build-tools-23-0-0-preview

Comment: what about `buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"` ?

Comment: I've tried also this and all the explained solutions, but same here.

Comment: @mum007 make sure your `sdk manager` all updated and then `clean-rebuild-restart-sync-run`.

Answer (score 0):

you have go to "android sdk manager" and download "android sdk build-tools" version 23.0.2 after done download

go to "build.gradle" and use `buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"`

try this way

keep your internet connection
click on "File" on android studio toolbar and click on "invalidate Caches/Restart..." and choose "invalidate and restart"

Comment: in build.gradle using that version?